# How should I set data type for my media using laravel nova spatie media library

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova, laravel-medialibrary, nova-media-library

I would like to be able to only upload PDF.

I have seen methods [here](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v8/working-with-media-collections/defining-media-collections/) `acceptsFile` or `acceptsMimeTypes` that could do the trick, but it seems that it will give an error at submiting the file.

I was loooking for a way to only be able to select pdf.

With the built-in laravel File resource, I was able to use :

```
->acceptedTypes('.pdf')
```

How should I do this with this plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem does not reside in Laravel.

To be able to select only PDF files in the browser, specify the content type in the HTML source:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf" />
```

Check it out :)

Comment: yep, but laravel nova doesn't work this way. https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/file-fields.html

Comment: Oh I get it now, sorry. Came across this though (see @Krato’s reply)  https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1345